# Owl carousel - settings and styling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm trying to achieve a similar carousel as below ([live preview](https://mymagic.my/)):
[image]

I've been fiddling around with the settings but no luck so far despite having the same structure and classes. Here's what I have so far:

[image]

My code snippet as below:

JS:

```
$('#lgi__slider .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  dots: false,
  autoWidth: true,
  stagePadding: 0,
  margin: 15,
  nav: true,
  navText: ['<i class="icon-left-small"></i>', '<i class="icon-right-small"></i>'],
  navContainer: '#lgi__slider',
  navClass: [ 'lgi__btn lgi__btn--prev', 'lgi__btn lgi__btn--next' ],
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1,
    },
    768: {
      items: 2,
      autoWidth: false,
    },
    992: {
      items: 3,
      autoWidth: false,
    },
    1310: {
      items: 3,
      autoWidth: false,
      margin: 30,
    }
  }
});
```

PHP/HTML:

```
    <section class="lgi">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="lgi__block lgi__block-2">
        <div class="lgi__head">

            <h2 class="h0">PRODUCTS BY <?php echo $model->title ?></h2>
            <p class="lgi__quote"></p>
        </div>
        <div class ="lgi__slider" id="lgi__slider">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-loaded owl-drag">  
            <?php foreach ($model->products as $product): ?>
            <div class="lgi__item">
                <a class="lgi__item-inner main-enterprise-image" data-enterprise-id="<?php echo $product['id']; ?>" data-image="<?php echo ImageHelper::thumb(320, 320, $product->image_cover) ?>" data-category="<?php echo $product->productCategory->title;?>" data-desc="<?php echo $product->text_short_description;?>" data-title="<?php echo $product['title']; ?>">
                    <div class="lgi__block-img">
                        <img class="lgi__img" src="<?php echo ImageHelper::thumb(320, 320, $product->image_cover) ?>" />
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lgi__title stripe">
                        <h4> <?php echo $product['title']; ?></h4>
                        <h6> 
                            <?php echo $product->productCategory->title; ?>
                        </h6>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div> 
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Greatly appreciate if anyone can point out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The same element has class `owl-carousel` and id `lgi__slider`. Remove space from `$('#lgi__slider .owl-carousel')` to `$('#lgi__slider.owl-carousel')` or use only id `$('#lgi__slider')` selector and try.

Comment: If I do $('#lgi__slider.owl-carousel') it will look the same but if I only put the id, the slides will be in different lines.

Comment: If you see make same fiddle reference that would be easy to get the problems.